# IPersistFile Load undefined return value

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, mingw

I'm currently trying to port the example [Resolving a Shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Shellink_Resolving_Shortcut) on MSDN to a QT application built with MinGW 4.8.1.

My code (stripped of error checks for shortness) currently looks like this:

```
QFileInfo shortcut("C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\ShortCut.lnk");

HRESULT apiResult;
IShellLink *shellLink;

apiResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                             IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*) &shellLink);

IPersistFile *persistFile;
apiResult = shellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**) &persistFile);

WCHAR shortcutLocationWchar[MAX_PATH];
QString shortcutLocation = QDir::toNativeSeparators(shortcut.absoluteFilePath());
shortcutLocation.toWCharArray(shortcutLocationWchar);

apiResult = persistFile->Load(shortcutLocationWchar, STGM_READ);

apiResult = shellLink->Resolve(NULL, SLR_NO_UI);

WCHAR shortcutTargetWchar[MAX_PATH];
WIN32_FIND_DATA winFindData;
apiResult = shellLink->GetPath(shortcutTargetWchar, MAX_PATH, &winFindData, 0);

QString shortcutTarget = QString::fromWCharArray(shortcutTargetWchar);
```

At the moment `IPersistFile::Load` fails with return value `0x80070002`, what is neither defined in [its API Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), nor the `winerr.h` header nor Google seems to come up with any useful results.

Any suggestions what is going wrong here?

Comment: You sure that's a good string to be using `C:\Users\MyUserName\ShortCut.lnk`? (I realize it's an example, but those path separators \ should be \\ for a simple string)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, but this happened only for the snippet here.

Comment: The `HRESULT` you get is `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`

Comment: Any reason to not use the qt-native [`symlinkTarget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html)? Which also indicates that the `absoluteFilePath()` call mangles the slashes to something that will not be valid for use in `persistFile->load`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: As I haven't know about `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`, do you have any doc describing when to use it?

Comment: @Petesh: I don't use `QFileInfo::symlinkTarget()` because I would also be interested in the working directory in a later step, which QT can't give me, as far as I know. And shouldn't the slashes be correct if I run them trough `QDir::toNativeSeparators`? At least they look like it...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746.aspx, as easily found by a quick search.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I found that link, too. But it doesn't really give an explanation WHY I have to use macro, as `IPersistFile::Load` already returns a `HRESULT` and the macro would expect a `DWORD`.

Comment: Look at the documentation more carefully. You can clearly see that `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()` sets the HRESULT's facility to `FACILITY_WIN32` and its scode to the Win32 error code.  When you encounter an HRESULT value that you don't understand, extract its facility and scode values, where the facility tells you how to interpret the scode. `FACILITY_WIN32` is a Win32 error code, whereas [`FACILITY_ITF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679751.aspx) is interface-defined, etc. In this case, `0x80070002` consists of `Severity=Error`, `Facility=FACILITY_WIN32`, and `Scode=2`.

Comment: I didn't say you should use this macro to interpret the result. I said, in effect, that `IPersistFile::Load` used this macro to *produce* said result, which gives you a hint as to how to interpret it. As @RemyLebeau discusses, the 7 in `0x80070002` is the tell-tale sign that the lower 16 bits (2 in this case) represent Win32 error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed an important line in the [API documentation for QString::toWcharArrar()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#toWCharArray):

> **Note:** This function does not append a null character to the array.

So the correct way would convert the shortcut file name to `WCHAR` array is

```
WCHAR shortcutLocationWchar[MAX_PATH];
QString shortcutLocation = QDir::toNativeSeparators(shortcut.absoluteFilePath());
int l = shortcutLocation.toWCharArray(shortcutLocationWchar);
shortcutLocationWchar[l] = L'\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value `0x80070002` means that the system cannot find the file specified. Thus you your file path is incorrect. I think you should rather write it as:

```
QFileInfo shortcut("C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\ShortCut.lnk");
```

I would also simplify your code in the following way:

```
QString shortcutLocation = shortcut.absoluteFilePath();
apiResult = persistFile->Load((LPCWSTR)shortcutLocation.constData(), STGM_READ);
```

And finally, why do you need to use Windows API, and mix it with Qt, when you can use fully Qt based solution that is much simpler and shorter. For example, I would do this:

```
QFileInfo shortcut(QFileInfo shortcut("D:\\downloads\\sk.lnk.lnk");
QString shortcutTarget ;
if (shortcut.isSymLink()) {
    shortcutTarget = shortcut.symLinkTarget();
}
```

Comment: The file name I'm (really) using in comes from a directory listing, any only ends in only one `.lnk`, so I think that it should be correct, as I'm able to open the file with QT. I'll try your simplification to see if it changes something. Please see my comment above, why I don't use `QFileInfo::symlinkTarget()`.

Comment: @Hurzelchen, from the windows console you can do: `cd C:\Users\MyUserName` and than call `dir` command to see what is the name of your `ShortCut.lnk` shortcut. For me it is `ShortCut.lnk.lnk`.

Comment: When using `dir` it also shows up as `ShortCut.lnk`. Keep in mind that Windows Explorer always removes the `.lnk` extension from shortcuts.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought, you named your file `ShortCut.lnk`, but actually, it has no extension. I have updated my answer.